# Paypal Rest API - Creating payment using paypal account payment resource

Tags: python, django, paypal

Using python and django, I'm trying to create a payment on paypal using REST API account payment resource. Everything works when I use curl. In the Django view I get the token alright but when I try to make a payment using it, I get "HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized" error.

Here is my curl that works:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Authorization:Bearer ***my_token***' -d '{ "intent":"sale", "redirect_urls":{ "return_url":"http://www.myurl.com", "cancel_url":"http://www.myurl.com"}, "payer":{ "payment_method":"paypal" },"transactions":[{"amount":{ "total":"0.10", "currency":"USD"},"description":"This is the Test payment transaction description."}]}'
```

Here is my Django view that has a problem when :

```
import urllib2, base64

token = "***my_token***"
values = {
          "intent":"sale",
          "redirect_urls":{
            "return_url":"http://www.myurl.com",
            "cancel_url":"http://www.myurl.com"
          },
          "payer":{
            "payment_method":"paypal"
          },
          "transactions":[
            {
              "amount":{
                "total":"0.10",
                "currency":"USD"
              },
              "description":"This is the Test payment transaction description."
            }
          ]}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)

request1 = urllib2.Request("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s' % token).replace('\n', '')
request1.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
request1.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer %s" % base64string) 

result1 = urllib2.urlopen(request1 , data)
response = result1.read()
```

In other words I'm trying to make the curl work in my view.

Thanks.

Comment: `request1 = urllib2.Request("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr")`

Comment: @catherine. I was expecting json data that has a token but using your address takes me to paypal screen without any form.

Comment: I have same problem, any solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're running into the same thing I was, but I was trying to create payments for a third party paypal account to which I had not properly requested permission. Turns out I needed to use the Permissions API to request proper permissions.

See this link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/

Answer (score -2):

First make a request to `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token` with basic auth to get Bearer token and then make the REST call(`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment`) with the Bearer token.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

Use PayPal SDK [paypalrestsdk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paypalrestsdk) to simplify your  Python code.

1. https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python - README
2. https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples - Samples

Comment: I'm able to get the Bearer token as I indicated. My problem is using it to make the payment.

Comment: Replace the line `request1.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)` with `request1.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer %s" % bearer_token)`

Comment: I get the same error using ("Authorization", "Bearer %s" % bearer_token)

Comment: Don't have to do base64 encoding for bearer token, So remove the `base64string = base64.encodestring('%s' % token).replace('\n', '')` statement and use the token directly `request1.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer %s" % token)`

Comment: PayPal released a new sdk for python. For more information: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python